# How to solve this issue with nested routes in react (admin layout)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have a problem with routing in my react application. I have HOC component called "ProtectedRoute" which should show my sidebar(there I render{this.props.children}) + specified route, but when I want do navigate to /home/profile, i have always being redirected to /home/dashboard. Can you please take a look at my code and propose a solution? Thanks

```
import React from 'react';
import Login from '../pages/Login/Login';
import ProtectedRoute from '../components/shared/ProtectedRoute';
import history from '../history';
import AdminLayout from '../layouts/AdminLayout';

const router = (
    <Router history={history}>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
            <ProtectedRoute path="/home" component={AdminLayout} />
            <Route render={() => (<div>Sorry. This page does not exist.</div>)} />
        </Switch>
    </Router>
);

export default router;
```

```
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Sidebar from '../components/Sidebar/Sidebar';
import Dashboard from '../pages/Dashboard/Dashboard'
import EmployeeProfile from '../pages/EmployeeProfile/EmployeeProfile';
import { Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

class AdminLayout extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Sidebar>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/home/dashboard" exact component={Dashboard} />
                        <Route path="/home/profile" component={EmployeeProfile} />
                        <Route render={() => (<div>Sorry. This page does not exist.</div>)} />
                    </Switch>
                </Sidebar>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default AdminLayout;
```

Comment: How is it that you're trying to navigate to `"/home/profile"`? Is it a button click or some other action?

Comment: @YannickK hmm, this is weird, when I'm navigating through browser and using react's link tag, it doesnt work, but when I navigate using history.push({path: '...'}) it works...

Comment: May want to try using `exact path` and see if that changes the behaviour.

Comment: @YannickK it will probably work with exact but then I will have problem with multiple levels of nested routes..., nevermind, it works when I'm using history object, that's enough for now. Thank you so much for your help... :)